# How to modify label order in plotly x chart base on category in data?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, bubble-chart

```
Bldt = [go.Scatter(x=BBdata['horsepower'],
               y=BBdata['mpg'],
              text=BBdata['name'],
               mode='markers',
               marker=dict(size=2*BBdata['cylinders'])
              )]

Bllayout = go.Layout(title='Bubble Chart')
Blfig = go.Figure(data=Bldt, layout=Bllayout)
Blfig.update_layout(title_text='Bubble Chart', title_x=0.5,
                   xaxis = dict(
        type="category",
        tickmode = 'array'))
```

The result I wanted is x-axes order in ASC/DESC, not random.
anyone can help? Already try modify update.layout but it's not help.

[image]

Comment: What if you sort your data first? `BBdata.sort_values(by=["horsepower"], inplace=True)` and then create your `go.Scatter` object

Comment: The solution that u gave is correct. thanks a lot.

If I allow to ask a question again, there are value of data more than 130 (x-axis) as displayed on chart above. How to include it? Why my bubblechart did not cover all indexed value?

Comment: glad to hear it works! I am going to add what I wrote as an answer. can you ask your follow up question as a separate question? I need more information to help answer your question and I think it's different from your original question

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your data first before you create your `go.Scatter` object:

```
BBdata.sort_values(by=["horsepower"], inplace=True)
```